# using httpRequest headers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, request, http-request

```
byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
request.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
request.Headers.Add(string.format("infoAsString, {0}", infoAsString))

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{      
    requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
```

iv tried this and in debug when code reaches the request.Headers it throws : Specified value does not have a ':' separator. Parameter name: header

Also tried:

```
request.Headers.Add("infoAsString, {0}", infoAsString)
```

&

```
request.Headers.Add("infoAsString : {0}", infoAsString)
```

&

```
request.Headers.Add(infoAsString)
```

no joy...please advise

Comment: I'm surprised it compiled some of those.

Answer (score 2):

Headers is a `NameValueCollection` and takes members with a name and a value.

You should be doing

```
request.Headers.Add("infoAsString", infoAsString)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried this and it seems to work ok (No errors) but when debug going to requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);, and the debug jumps over to the server, infoAsString is coming back as NULL....any idea as to why?

Comment: Can you post your server code where it tries to read the header?