# Adding Header to Web Request throws an error

Tags: vb.net, http, header

When attempting to add a value to the header of an HTTP request, I get the following error:

> Specified value does not have a ':' separator. Parameter name: header

To add the header I am using the following code:

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)

    Dim soapXML As New XmlDocument()
    soapXML.LoadXml(soapEnvelope)

    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=""utf-8"""
    request.Accept = "text/xml"

    Using stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        soapXML.Save(stream)
    End Using
```

I have been looking all over the place and haven't found anybody who has had any similar errors, outside of this SO question: [using httpRequest headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552803/using-httprequest-headers)
Which didn't help much.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong here?

**EDIT 1: Added all the code that I currently have that creates my web request.**

Comment: what is in `action`?

Comment: action is the url for the specific action of the web service. For example:
    `action = "http://<address>/DoSomething"`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2435843/1704458

Comment: Mine is very similar to that which you posted. Unfortunately, it seems it acts differently, and I'm not sure why. I made sure that my SOAPAction URL is correct from the page of the web service. It is even sending back that error from within the XML that is returned by the SOAP service.

Comment: for heck of it, try to use this overload `.Add(String.Format("SOAPAction:{1}", action))`

Comment: It so happened that my web service was outdated, and was missing a few arguments on the server. Thanks T.S. for all the help, but it was a different issue altogether. Chalk this one up to an id-107 error ;). Sorry to waste your time man.

Comment: no problems. happens